# Closing Menu on Outside Click on page with iFrames

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to use the trick outlined [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element) to close a navigation menu on a page I've designed. However, the majority of the space on the page is taken up by an iframe that loads articles stored on the same server as the page containing the iframe.

If I click on any of the elements on the parent page, the menu closes as it should. However, clicking on any of the space within the iframe does not close the menu.

I'm assuming this is because the parent page does not capture events happening inside of the iframe. Like I've said, both pages are stored on the same server, so how can I capture the click to close my menu when the user clicks within the iframe?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menucontainer">
<nav id="mobilemenu">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="menutrigger">&#9776; Menu</span></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<nav id="fullmenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="page1.html" target="content">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="page2.html" target="content">Menu Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="page3.html" target="content">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="page4.html" target="content">Menu Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div id="frame">
        <iframe name="content" id="content" src="intro.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[target='content']").click(function() {
        if ($("#mobilemenu").css("display") == "block" ){
            $('#fullmenu').hide();
        }
    });
    $('html').click(function() {
        $('#fullmenu').hide();
    });
    $('#menucontainer').click(function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.menutrigger').click(function() {
        $('#fullmenu').toggle();
    });
});
```

**CSS:** (Added because it occurred to me it might be affecting things)

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

nav, #frame { position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 100%; }

#content { height: 100%; width: 100%; }

#frame { top: 38px; bottom: 14px; }

nav { width: 100%; z-index: 100; }

#fullmenu { display: none; position: absolute; top: 38px; width: 100%; }

#mobilemenu { display: block; height: 38px; top: 0; background: #333; }

.menutrigger { font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; padding: 1px 8px; color: #FFF; cursor: pointer; }

#frame { top: 38px; bottom: 14px; }

nav ul { position: relative; width: 100%; background: #333; list-style: none; display: inline-block; padding: 0; }

nav ul:after { clear: both; }

nav ul li { height: 29px; float: none; min-width: 110px; font-size: 14px; padding: 4px 4px; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif; }

nav ul li a { display: block; padding: 5px; color: #FFF; text-decoration: none; }

nav ul li:hover { background: #666; display: inline-block; height: 29px; }

nav ul li:hover a { color: #FFF; }
```

Answer (score 3):

The contents().click() does not work when the iframe is on a different domain. You'll get a cross-domain access error attempting to make the contents() call.

Answer (score 2):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2mRwb/17/)

Instead of

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#fullmenu').hide();
});
```

use

```
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#fullmenu').hide();
});

//get iframe contents and bind click on them.
$('#content').contents().click(function(){
    $('#fullmenu').hide();
});
```

Comment: I'm seeing where it works in the JFiddle, but it's not working on my end with the exact same click event you're using. I'm concerned that I'm using CSS z-index to make the menu float above the iframe, and that this might be interfering with things.

Answer (score 0):

For iframes with different domains, my solution is to send an event from the iframe with [Post Message API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and listen to it on the parent. This way the parent can perform any action when the iframe is clicked.

In parent page:

```
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  // DO SOMETHING
}, false);
```

In iframe:

```
window.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  parent.postMessage("click", "*");
}, false);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32300547)